# Is praying to God against what we say about God?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

We say God is Just. He never does injustice to anyone but still we pray to God for our interest. For example, Consider two shop-owners who have their shops adjacent to each other and they sell the same stuff. One prays that his sale increase. Now as he do so he wants God to do injustice because if his sale increases, the sale of other will consequently decrease.

On what argument such praying exist?

Even it is said in holy scriptures that God helps poor. But if everything is in this world, anyone can work hard and achieve then why holy scriptures say that.

Comment: "On what argument such praying exist?" On no argument... at most on human greed.

Comment: It is not necessarily so that the other shop owners sales will decrease.

Comment: Just because somebody prays to God about something does not mean that God will oblige, so what does it have to do with *him* being just? And God is big enough to understand people's desires to do well, and pray to him for it, even if they can not be granted simultaneously, or at all. In *this* world "anyone can work hard and achieve" is a fantasy, working helps but not without luck. Perhaps God can be faulted for creating such a world, but hardly for helping those who are out of luck in it.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy  From Economics point of view. It will decrease.

Comment: @Conifold you are taking different path. I am talking about what people do and what they say about God. We are nowhere talking about God's fair sense or justice.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA (+1)

Answer (score 1):

#### Unjust prayers

You correctly note that God `never does injustice to anyone but still we pray to God for our interest`, even when such a prayer entails injustice. This is however not a problem with prayer but rather our flawed application of it. Of course God will not grant a prayer for an unjust action; such a wish is, I think, probably to be counted as a sin.

#### Prayer generally

But of course these are not the only kinds of prayers. The more interesting question is, why pray at all? After all, God has perfect knowledge, and God's will is immutable, so if you are in the kind of trouble that God would help you with, God is already knows about it and is already either going to help you or not.

From Aquinas's *Summa Theologica*, Part 2.2, Question 83, On Prayer, Article 2, Whether it is becoming to pray?:

> Objection 1. It would seem that it is unbecoming to pray. Prayer seems to be necessary in order that we may make our needs known to the person to whom we pray. But according to Matthew 6:32, "Your Father knoweth that you have need of all these things." Therefore it is not becoming to pray to God.
>
> ...
>
> Reply to Objection 1. We need to pray to God, not in order to make known to Him our needs or desires but that we ourselves may be reminded of the necessity of having recourse to God's help in these matters.

There you have it. We pray for ourselves, to remember our place in the world. That's Catholic dogma, at least, but the logic holds true for any religion with a similar conception of God as all-powerful, all-knowing, and all-good.

#### Poverty and the Bible

You end asking why the Bible says that God helps the poor when people can achieve success through hard work. However it is *not* the case that our fortunes are entirely under our control; this is a basic result of living in a world with other people and changing conditions. Our success is highly determined by the place in and kind of society we are born in, general economic trends, natural disasters, etc.

Humans have free will, so I think we can safely assume that economic trends are, generally, not the kind of thing God would interfere with. Similarly society is shaped by humans to be unequal. That's on us, not God. That leaves natural disasters and the like. For that, see [this excellent summary](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/evil/), and, if you still have questions,---and it's a fair bet that you will---ask them here!

Answer (score 0):

> Is praying to God against what we say about God?

Isn't praying also a speech act? (i.e. prayer is part of "what we say about God") I'm not sure I take your meaning, but if you are asking, "is it contradictory that a just deity would honor an unjust prayer"? well... it has been said that deity works in mysterious ways and who are we to judge?

> We say God is Just. He never does injustice to anyone but still we pray to God for our interest.

Is deity necessarily just? In one sense, justice is fairness, another it is simply the administration of law. If the deity you speak of makes the laws, then everything they do is just. If the deity you speak of is the arbiter of what is fair or not, then everything they do may very well be fair even if you disagree.

> For example, Consider two shop-owners who have their shops adjacent to each other and they sell the same stuff. One prays that his sale increase. Now as he do so he wants God to do injustice because if his sale increases, the sale of other will consequently decrease.

Is his prayer for "sale increase" also a prayer for "his neighbors sales decrease"? I.e. does this prayer explicitly request an injustice? Couldn't the praying shop owner pray for better business without harming his neighbors? Couldn't a just deity answer an individual prayer for betterment without the detriment of others? Would a just deity honor a prayer for injustice? If the praying shop owner prayed "dear God, please make my business so successful it drives my neighbor out of business" would a just deity drive the neighbor out of business, or, use this prayer as an opportunity to help the praying shop owner see the humanity in his neighbor's business?

Also, if there were only one customer in the world and that customer could only shop at one of these stores or the other, this resulting "injustice" might be the case, and I can see how you might imagine such an injustice given the standard rational model of supply and demand, however, a map is not the territory in the same way a scale model train set is not going to carry full sized people and cargo.

> On what argument such praying exist?

I don't know what you mean by this question.

> Even it is said in holy scriptures that God helps poor. But if everything is in this world, anyone can work hard and achieve then why holy scriptures say that.

Likely the scriptures say things like "God helps the poor" because the church and temple and synagogue generally do a lot to help the poor with food and clothing, community, spiritual guidance and at times shelter from the storm.